# Scalatest using main resources, not test resources

Tags: java, scala, maven, junit, scalatest

I have a scalatest case that uses both Scala and Java code, and within the Java parts of the code there is a call to:

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("/dbLocations.properties");
```

This is fine for other sections of the code that use JUnit, but I'm rewriting the Scala tests classes to use Scalatest (someone wrote them with JUnit), and when executing my test that runs the above code, the properties it loads are from src/**main**/resources, not src/**test**/resources.

Is there any configuration I'm missing? I'm using Maven because of the large Java portions of the project (And overarching developer experience with Maven over SBT).

Comment: to be sure, from your question I assume that you have a similarly named property file in the `main/resources` folder?

Comment: yes i do indeed, which contains the values used for production

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It ended up being a Maven issue, the dependency JAR in my local Maven repo (which I have the source for) had the production values in it. I now create a test-jar for that dependency using the maven-jar-plugin:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

And then included that as a dependency in the other project, with the scope set to 'test', so the test-jar is only on the classpath whilst I am testing, being aware of placing the test-jar first in the classpath so that when they're both on it, the testing resources are pulled in before detecting the other (production) JAR:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>naughty-dependency</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.5-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>test-jar</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>naughty-dependency</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.5-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

In my mind seems a little bit hacky but it works!

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, it should work as is.

Did you check the maven file to see if, by any chance, some `pom` configuration is excluding the `src/test/resources` folder from the test classpath?